# /index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

My JSF web application shows the following error:

> /index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource.

My directory structure is:

```
- Java Resource
-- src
--- br.com.k19.controle
---- NumeroAleatorioBean.java
--- resources
- JavaScript Resources
- build
- WebContent
-- META-INF
-- Web Pages
--- index.xhtml
--- formulario.xhtml
-- Web-Inf
```

Where do I need to put my `/index.xhtml` in this structure?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `WebContent` folder represents the web content. You placed the `index.xhtml` file inside `Web Pages` subfolder so the right URL would be

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/Web Pages/index.xhtml
```

and thus *not*

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/index.xhtml
```

as you seemed to expect.

If you want to have it on the context root, just get rid of the `Web Pages` folder altogether and move those `.xhtml` files directly inside `WebContent` folder, in the same level as `META-INF` and `WEB-INF`:

```
ProjectName
 |-- Java Resources
 |    `-- src
 |         `-- br.com.k19.controle
 |              `-- NumeroAleatorioBean.java
 |-- resources
 |-- JavaScript Resources
 |-- build
 `-- WebContent
      |-- META-INF
      |-- WEB-INF
      |    |-- faces-config.xml
      |    `-- web.xml
      |-- index.xhtml
      `-- formulario.xhtml
```

Note: Java is case sensitive. `Web-Inf` is definitely not the same as `WEB-INF`. Be careful or you'll have a security hole.

Comment: Move all to Webcontent but error continue. Have any configuration in my web.xml with:   
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>

Comment: `Webcontent` or `WebContent`? Casing makes difference. Did you rebuild/redeploy/restart the project and the server? The `*.xhtml` pattern is fine. I'd remove the `/faces/*` pattern, it's an useless leftover from JSF 1.0 and not really recommended as it only causes confusion among starters.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue recently. I tried cleaning the Tomcat **Work Directory, Clean**, and **Publish**.
After that, when I started the server, the application was running smooth.

For independent tomcat server, clean dir --> **temp, work,** and inside **webApp** directory, **remove all the existing unarchived project.**
*Restart* the Tomcat, it worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please feel free to take a [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site, and if you need additional help with the site, check [this](//stackoverflow.com/help) out. Oh, and if you ever run into issues that the help page doesn't cover, feel free to ask on [meta](//meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: This answer helped me out when everything was configured correctly under Wildfly. I deleted the tmp and deployment folders. It is however not related to original question.